# induced maps between group $C^*$-algebras

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, harmonic-analysis, operator-theory

Suppose $G,H$ are two locally compact groups, if there is a  injective homomorphism $\phi:G\to H$, can $\phi$ induce the $*$-homomorphism between group $C^*$-algebras $C^*(G)$ and $C^*(H)$? If it exists, is it injective?

Comment: No, and that’s much the point of Rieffel ([1974](//ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=50:5489)): “Actually, if H is a closed but not open subgroup of the locally compact group G, then the group C*-algebra, C*(H), of H is not a subalgebra of C*(G), but rather acts as an algebra of right centralizers [29] on C*(G).”

Comment: I saw an example: consider $\Bbb Z\subset \Bbb R$, I cannoe see why there does not exist $*$-hommomorphisms between $C^*(\Bbb Z)$ and $C^*(\Bbb R)$.

Comment: More simply $\{0\}\subset\mathbf R$. What subalgebra of $C^*(\mathbf R)$ would  $C^*(\{0\})$ be?

Comment: But $C^*(0)$ is 0,  we can get the zero $*$ homomorphism from 0 to $C^*(R)$.

Comment: The $C^*$-algebra of a one-element group is $\mathbf C$, not $\{0\}$.